# An equilateral polygon which is cyclic is a regular polygon.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

An equilateral polygon which is cyclic is a regular polygon.
How to prove this statement? Can anyone please help me by giving some hints?

Comment: Each edge subtends the same angle at the centre of the circumscribing circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

First, let's convince ourselves that the diagram will look roughly like this given a polygon with $n$ sides.   (Here, $n=7$.) Since the points are all on the boundary of the circle and the distances between them are all the same, there are only two places where the neighbors to any vertex can go (as seen by the circle centered at $G$).  The vertices also must only go around the circle once or otherwise the edges would cross and we wouldn't have a legitimate polygon.

That said, add radii to the center of the circle as shown in the diagram.  All of the $n$ triangles are isosceles and congruent, since the legs are all radii of the circle and the $n$-gon is given to be equilateral.  Therefore, the base angles of the triangle all have the same measure $\theta$.  Thus, every internal angle of the $n$-gon has a measure of $2\theta$ and the $n$-gon is also equilangular and hence regular.